Beginner Issue understand Documentation - Ktor
I am working with ktor to perform HTTP requests. Unfortunately I have some problems with the documentation of ktor.
Errors can occur when calling the .request() method. But I can't find anything in the documentation of .request() if errors or which errors can be thrown.
In the Java documentation there is a sub-item with "Throws" for each method declaration which lists all errors that can be thrown.
Example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read-char:A-int-int-
I would therefore be very happy if someone could explain to me how to search for it in such cases, or how to search the documentation for it in general.
Thanks :-)

Unfortunately, there is no documentation of all possible exceptions for all public methods. The actual exception types depend on the engine and the platform because Ktor doesn't catch them to unify.
You can experiment with the code to trigger exceptions and determine their specific types.
